# Gmp package bug in vardef suffix macros?

Tags: metapost

I think I am running into a gmp bug where a vardef macro name "mymacro@#" gets written in the generated metapost file as "mymacro@##". This is my first time using gmp package and I could be missing something. Can anyone confirm this is a bug? If it is indeed a bug, is there some workaround or a possible fix?

TIA!

The TeX input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}
u=2cm;

vardef mymacro@#=
  pair @#.mid;
  @# := (0u, 0u) -- (50u, 75u);
  @#.mid := 0.5[(0u, 0u), (50u, 75u)];
enddef;

path a;

mymacro.a;
draw a;
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

Log file:

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.00 (TeX Live 2019) (kpathsea version 6.3.1)  29 NOV 2019 13:41
**foo+mp0001
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./foo+mp0001.mp
>> mymacro.a
! Isolated expression.
<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.14  mymacro.a;

I couldn't find an `=' or `:=' after the
expression that is shown above this error message,
so I guess I'll just ignore it and carry on.

>> unknown path a
! Improper `addto'.
<to be read again> 
                   withpen
draw->...:also(EXPR0)else:doublepath(EXPR0)withpen
                                                  .currentpen.fi._op_
<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.15  draw a;

This expression should have specified a known path.
So I'll not change anything just now.

[1] )
1 output file written: foo+mp0001.mps
```

The metapost file:

```
%% Do not edit, this file has been generated
%% automatically by foo.tex via gmp.sty

outputtemplate:= "%j.mps";
beginfig(1);
u=2cm;

vardef mymacro@##= pair @##.mid;
 @## := (0u, 0u) -- (50u, 75u);
 @##.mid := 0.5[(0u, 0u), (50u, 75u)];
 enddef;

path a;
 mymacro.a;
 draw a;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug, yes. When scanning the `mpost` environment, the package does not set the catcode of `#` to `12`, so TeX doubles it, as it usually would. You need to add `\do\#` to `\gmp@otherchars`:

```latex
\makeatletter %                                       added vvvvv
\def\gmp@otherchars{\do\!\do\=\do\:\do\"\do\?\do\'\do\`\do\|\do\#}
\makeatother
```

Adding that (and reducing the length of the line a bit to fit in the page), the code works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\makeatletter
\def\gmp@otherchars{\do\!\do\=\do\:\do\"\do\?\do\'\do\`\do\|\do\#}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}
u=2cm;

vardef mymacro@#=
  pair @#.mid;
  @# := (0u, 0u) -- (5u, 7u);
  @#.mid := 0.5[(0u, 0u), (5u, 7u)];
enddef;

path a;

mymacro.a;
draw a;
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Will accept this as the answer.